# could not use variable get from txt file in robot framework

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I try to get variable `${var_Master}` from a txt file and put it in to into list box and `${ValSub}` is working fine, but I got error on var `${var_Master}`:

> **InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified   (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167) 
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940
>   (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

With the below code example:

```
  ${var_sub}    Get File    ../resources/var_sub.txt
 @{list}    Split To Lines  ${var_sub}
 ${var_Master}    Get File    ../resources/var_master.txt
 :FOR       ${line}    IN      @{list}

 \   ${ValSub}=   Get Variable Value  ${line}
 \   sleep      1s
 \  select from list by value       name=merchant_id     ${ValSub}
 \  select from list by value       name=master_marchant_id     ${var_Master}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to solve my problem

```
${var_master}    Get File    ../resources/var_master.txt
     @{list}    Split To Lines  ${var_master}
     :FOR       ${lineb}    IN      @{list}
     \   ${ValMas}=   Get Variable Value  ${lineb}
    ${var_sub}    Get File    ../resources/var_sub.txt
     @{list}    Split To Lines  ${var_sub}

     :FOR       ${line}    IN      @{list}
     \   ${ValSub}=   Get Variable Value  ${line}

     \   sleep      1s
     \   select from list by value       name=master_marchant_id     ${ValMas}
     \   select from list by value       name=merchant_id     ${ValSub}
```

Comment: In this approach I don't understand the section that uses `Get Variable Value` and then proceeds to use `Convert To String`. In my view `${line}` already holds a string value and as such should not need any casting and converting.

Comment: Yes i was forgot to delete that line. i just put for test .

Comment: There should also be no need to use `Get Variable Value` in this example either. As `${line}` and `${valSub}` are both regular variables and hold the exact same value.

Answer (score 0):

In Robot Framework there is no need to create custom import routine to create variables as there is a standard keyword for it: `Import Variables` ([Documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Variables)).

In the below example I'm using a file in the YAML markup language which allows for the creation of specific Python and [Robot variable types](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-file-as-yaml) like lists, dictionaries and scalars in human readable format. It is also possible to import a python file declaring the objects as well.

In this example I've created a mock scalar variable `master` and a mock list variable `list` to prove that looping is possible and mocked the `Select From List By Value` as a custom keyword.

**vars.yaml**

```
master: master value

list:
  - item 1
  - item 2
  - item 3
```

**example.robot**

```
*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    Import Variables    ${EXECDIR}/vars.yaml

    :FOR       ${line}    IN      @{list}   
    \   sleep      1s   
    \   select from list by value       name=master_marchant_id     ${master}   
    \   select from list by value       name=merchant_id     ${line}    

*** Keywords *** 
Select From List By Value
    [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${value}
    Log    Selecting "${value}" from "${locator}" element.
```

Comment: yes thanks you, but the Var in my txt file is geting by robot Append file . So can i append my var to vars.yaml ?

Comment: In the above example the variable file is imported by the test case in Robot Framework. You can use the `Import Variables` keyword to import variables stored in Python files and YAML files. Whether or not your file can be converted entirely really depends on the contents and it's use elsewhere but I'm confident that it can be replaced.